# How to get ZoneId, LocalDateTime and Instant from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, parsing, time

I'm using the below code to parse a date string:

```
    String time = "2 Jun 2019 03:51:17 PM ACST";
    String pattern = "d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z"; // z detects the time zone (ACST here)
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

 // ZonedDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(time)).atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Adelaide"));
 // localDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

The `formatter.parse(time)` already has both epoch time and time zone when I inspect it through debugging:

```
// formatter.parse(time) :
{InstantSeconds=1559456477},ISO,Australia/Adelaide resolved to 2019-06-02T15:51:17
```

My question is how to extract time zone (here Australia/Adelaide) from `formatter.parse(time)` which is of `Parsed` type to use the time zone dynamically in `atZone()` at this line? :

```
ZonedDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(time)).
                                     atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Adelaide"));
```

Even Furthur, how to extract the `InstantSeconds=1559456477` from the `formatter.parse(time)` response to avoid taking the more steps below to get epoch timestamp? :

```
ZonedDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(time)).
                                     atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Adelaide"));

localDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Aren't you over-complicating? `ZonedDateTime.parse(time, formatter)` gives you a `ZonedDateTime` with the correct zone (except perhaps if the abbreviation was ambiguous, they often are). Or `ZonedDateTime.from(formatter.parse(time))` if for some reason you prefer. Similarly to get *only* the zone you may use `ZoneId.from(formatter.oarse(time))`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, you're correct. I wasn't aware of nor `ZonedDateTime.parse(time, formatter)` is there similar to `LocalDateTime.parse()` nor `ZoneId.from()`. So to achive the epoch time in one line, this works fine: `ZonedDateTime.parse(time, formatter).toInstant().toEpochMilli();`; except for where we would need the `zoneID` eplicitly that `ZoneId.from(formatter.oarse(time))` comes in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTimeFormatter.parse` method return the [TemporalAccessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) which contains date, time and some other information and you can get that information by querying

```
default <R> R query(TemporalQuery<R> query)
```

> Framework-level interface defining read-only access to a temporal object, such as a date, time, offset or some combination of these.
>
> This is the base interface type for date, time and offset objects. It is implemented by those classes that can provide information as fields or queries.

[TemporalQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html) is functional interface

> The most common implementations are method references, such as LocalDate::from and ZoneId::from. Additional common queries are provided as static methods in TemporalQueries.

```
String time = "2 Jun 2019 03:51:17 PM ACST";
String pattern = "d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

TemporalAccessor parsedTime = formatter.parse(time);

ZoneId zone = parsedTime.query(ZoneId::from);

LocalDateTime localDateTime = parsedTime.query(LocalDateTime::from);

Instant instant = parsedTime.query(Instant::from);

System.out.println(zone);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
System.out.println(instant);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract the seconds or a zone id from a `DateTimeFormatter`, but you can do it using `ZonedDateTime` objects. Have a look at the following code and wonder about the fact that your time `String` seems to be in `"America/Manaus"`, which doesn't appear to be equal to *Australian Central Standard Time*…

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String time = "2 Jun 2019 03:51:17 PM ACST";
    String pattern = "d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z"; // z detects the time zone (ACST here)
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

    // parse a time object using the formatter and the time String
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
    // print it using a standard formatter
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    // extract the zone id
    ZoneId zoneId = zdt.getZone();
    // print the zone id
    System.out.println("This time is of zone " + zoneId);

    // retrieve the instant seconds
    Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
    // print the epoch seconds of another time zone
    System.out.println("Epoch seconds in Australia/Adelaide are " 
            + instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Adelaide")).toEpochSecond());
}
```

When I run this, it outputs

```
2019-06-02T15:51:17-04:00[America/Manaus]
This time is of zone America/Manaus
Epoch seconds in Australia/Adelaide are 1559505077
```

which shows how to extract the epoch seconds and the time zone, but somehow does not recognize ACST as what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why it gives you `America/Manaus` as the time zone (Is it your local time zone?). Your code still produces  `Australia/Adelaide` in the second line of output on my computer

Comment: @DummyBeginner interesting, it is not my locale, but Germany is... Really weird, maybe worth some more testing.