# Does a 'z' in a datetime String have different outputs in different locales?

Tags: java, timezone, zoneddatetime, java-time

Not long ago, I provided an answer to a question about how to extract the time zone from a `ZonedDateTime` parsed from a `String`.
It worked in general, but there were different outputs of the same code on OP's system an my one, which somehow doesn't let me go anymore.

[The related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265780/how-to-get-zoneid-localdatetime-and-instant-from-temporalaccessor/57266026?noredirect=1#comment101032041_57266026) asked how to get a `ZoneId` from a `ZonedDateTime` and I provided a way. Admittedly, it is not the accepted answer, but still seemed worth an upvote from someone.

The special thing about my answer is concerning the `'z'` in the pattern used to parse the time `String`. There is a time zone name in that `String` representing the zone `"Australia/Adelaide"` by `"... ACST"` (Australian Central Standard Time).

When I parse it on my system and print/format the `ZonedDateTime` using the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`, it prints the time in `"America/Manaus"` and having extracted the `ZoneId`, it is still that one from South America. OP stated in a comment below my answer, that on his system, at least one of the output lines shows the desired/correct `ZoneId`.

How is that possible? Does the system default locale have any influence on parsing the `'z'` in datetime `String`s?

This is the code from my answer in the question plus an output of my `ZoneId.systemDefault()`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String time = "2 Jun 2019 03:51:17 PM ACST";
    String pattern = "d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z"; // z detects the time zone (ACST here)
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

    // parse a time object using the formatter and the time String
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
    // print it using a standard formatter
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    // extract the zone id
    ZoneId zoneId = zdt.getZone();
    ZoneId sysDefault = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    // print the zone id
    System.out.println("Time zone of parsed String is " + zoneId);
    System.out.println("System default time zone is " + sysDefault);

    // retrieve the instant seconds
    Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
    // print the epoch seconds of another time zone
    System.out.println("Epoch seconds in Australia/Adelaide are " 
            + instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Adelaide")).toEpochSecond());
}
```

and its output is this:

```
2019-06-02T15:51:17-04:00[America/Manaus]
Time zone of parsed String is America/Manaus
System default time zone is Europe/Berlin
Epoch seconds in Australia/Adelaide are 1559505077
```

Can anyone point me to a mistake I have made or confirm and explain the influence of different system default `ZoneId`s on parsing a `String` to a `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: The safest thing to do is to set the locale of the formatter.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for the advice, it's useful. Do you know why the code produces different outputs in different locales?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Even AM/PM (`a`) is affected by locale, why would `z` not be?

Comment: @Sweeper Ok, thanks again... Then: Do you know *how* the code produces different outputs in different locales? I mean, how can my locale (`"Europe/Berlin"`) parse `"ACST"` to `"America/Manaus"` while an Australian system regards it as `"Australia/Adelaide"`?

Comment: Speculation: Different languages give time zones different abbreviations. Apparently, Eastern Standard Time can be abbreviated as HNE in French, so maybe that's what caused this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too have experienced ambiguous time zone abbreviations being parsed differently on different JVMs (also when providing a locale, so that is not the only issue). I don't think the exact behaviour is documented. In some cases the JVMs default time zone was chosen, I don't know if it will always be when it matches, though.

You can control the choice of time zone in ambiguous cases through the overloaded `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneText(TextStyle, Set<ZoneId>)` method.

An example where locale makes a difference: Europe/Berlin and many other European time zones will be formatted into `Central European Time` or `CET` in many locales. In a German locale they instead become `Mitteleuropäische Zeit` or `MET`.

Comment: I have neither found any exact documentation so far but at least I was aware of time zones being ambiguous. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268167/642706) is correct.

## ISO 8601

Furthermore, strings such as `"2 Jun 2019 03:51:17 PM ACST"` **should not be parsed**. Such formats should never be used to exchange date-time values. Such strings should be used only for presentation to the human user, not for data-exchange.

Would you try the exchange the monetary amount of `USD 23.67` as `twenty three dollars and sixty-seven cents in United States dollars` or as `vingt-trois dollars et soixante-sept cents en dollars des États-Unis`?

To exchange date-time values via text, always use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The sensible formats are designed to be unambiguous, easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans across cultures.

If using a time zone, use the [`ZonedDateTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString()) method to generate text. This method wisely extends the ISO 8601 format to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Adelaide" ) ;
String output = ZonedDateTime.now( z ).toString() ;
```

> 2020-02-10T06:30:57.756491+10:30[Australia/Adelaide]

Run that [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Ssfihe).

Parsing.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( output ) ;
```

Even better, use UTC values when the time zone is not directly relevant. To capture and communicate the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

Again, call `toString` & `parse` to generate and parse text in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString() ;
```

> 2020-02-09T20:07:42.718473Z